# friend of template method in template class, within a template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, friend

The description can be quite mind boggling so I get straight to the example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

template<typename T> class fr{
    static void privatestuff(){
        cout<<"private of "<<typeid(T).name()<<endl;
    }
public:
    template<typename TT> void callsomeone(){
        fr<TT>::privatestuff();
    }
    //template<typename TT> friend void fr<TT>::callsomeone<T>();
    //template<> template<typename TT> friend void fr<TT>::callsomeone<T>();
    //template<typename TT> template<> friend void fr<TT>::callsomeone<T>();
    //no other combinations... how to get it?
};

int main(){
    fr<bool> obj;
    obj.callsomeone<int>();
}
```

Basically, I want fr to be able to call `fr<int>::privatestuff`. But I'd like also to not expose more than what is needed, so make `fr<int>` friend of *only* `fr<bool>::callsomeone<int>`, not `fr<bool>::callsomeone<char>` or others.

I can count on c++11 if that's needed.

Comment: The question is in a comment in the code. What it means? No idea...

Comment: Do you want `callsomeone()` to be a friend of `fr`?

Comment: If I understand you correct - you need to declare callsomeone() as friend function of class fr to be able to call private fr's functions. Is it correct?

Comment: But `callsomeone()` is a *member function* template, it doesn't need to be a friend in the first place. Or am I missing something?

Comment: he wants fr<arbitrary>::callsomeone<T> to be a feiend of fr<T>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<class x> template<class y> friend void fr<x>::callsomeone();
```

You shall not pass any template arguments to callsomeone, because you want to befriend a function template, and not a specialization of it (in other words, you want to befriend all specializations of it).

Comment: Should that be fd<x>?  And where does y fit in?

Comment: doesn't this make declare friendness to any TT? I want to make it friend only when TT=T

Comment: no, his class template is called fr, not fd. I have no idea why he used fd in the friend declaration.

Comment: i believe i see.your intention now. i will look up in the spec the conditions of befriending a single function template secialization of a class template later, but i seem to remember that is not possible.

Comment: Could you link me these specs by the way?

Comment: the problem is that a.friend.declaration must refer.to somethong that can be.declared. but an instantiation of a.member.template first has its.enclosing template be instantiated. you are trying to reverse the instantiation of the enclosing and enclosed template, but there will never be.a declaration of fr<var>::f<fixed>

Comment: sorry for the typos, im writing.on my phone

Comment: @Lorenzo : The 'spec' in this case is the C++ standard, which is not freely available, however an extremely close draft is freely available [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf).